# Type Mismatch Error Exist Property in TestComplete tool

Tags: testcomplete

Today suddenly i got below type mismatch issue in various screen while executing script from test complete tool  .It was working fine last night and also working fine in other workstation today  without change . I really felt so bad because I am unable to figure out route cause and also same script worked well in last night  and other work station.I have reinstalled test complete 2-3 time but i didn't get answer why still happening this issue .

I tried to debug function and realized that it is giving error when 'Exists' method called .When i debug code line by line it is working fine but when i removed debug point then it is still giving same error .

Could you please help me on this?

Pain Point :- 1. Same Script working fine in other work station without change anytime[image]

[image]
Thanks you

Amit

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a delay to the test?